# How to use JavaFX KeyListeners?

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

I have an editable JavaFX ComboBox. 
A user must only be able to

1. type alphabets ('a' to 'z'), space and round braces ('(', ')') to enter the string
2. press tab to exit
3. press enter to exit

How to filter out every other key, modifiers etc?

I have read about and used event handlers like Key_Pressed, Key_Released but I am unable to figure out a straight-forward way to achieve the above.
 I am using Mac OS Yosemite, Java 8, latest version of JavaFX and
`public static final EventType<KeyEvent> KEY_TYPED` just does not work at all.
Below code is my attempt. The variable typedText stores the desired values.

```
comboBox.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        private final String[] allowedItems = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f",
        "g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
        "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ","(",")"};
        private final List data = Arrays.asList(allowedItems);
        private String tempInput;
        public boolean containsCaseInsensitive(String s, List<String> l){
            for (String string : l) {
                if (string.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                  return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            boolean b;
            b = event.isShiftDown();
            if (b) {
               if (event.getText().equals("(")) {
                    tempInput = "(";
                } else if (event.getText().equals(")")){
                    tempInput = ")";
                }
            } else {
                tempInput = event.getCode().toString().toLowerCase();
            }
            System.out.println("tempInput:"+tempInput);
            if (containsCaseInsensitive(tempInput, data)) {
            typedText = tempInput;
            System.out.println("typedText:"+typedText);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please share what you've achieved.

Comment: The JavaFX Event Loop is bidirectional, i.e. event messages are dispatched from the system and percolate down to your control ... and then percolate back up from your control back to the system.  The two abstractions FX defines for handling events are "filters" and "handlers".  A filter catches the message on its way to the control and a handler catches the message on its way back up.  For your case, you may wish to use a filter.  Otherwise the event will be processed by the control before it is processed by your handler.

Comment: Also, your code segment does not contain any calls to `consume()`.  If you do not consume the event message in your filter, then it will continue to be passed to the control.  When you wish to define custom behaviors that are different from the default behavior of the control, you'll need to consume the event so that the control doesn't also process the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Editor, which is a TextField in your case, and add a TextFormatter to it which restricts the input.

Tab works out of the box, but the "enter" keypress is a different matter, I simply request the focus in this example. Usually you'd navigate to the next item in the focus traversal list, but there's no future-proof api for that yet in JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
        comboBox.setValue("A");


        // restrict input
        TextField textField = comboBox.getEditor();
        TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
            change.setText(change.getText().replaceAll("[^a-z ()]", ""));
            return change;

        });
        textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

        // dummy textfield to jump to on ENTER press
        TextField dummyTextField = new TextField();

        comboBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if( e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                dummyTextField.requestFocus();
                e.consume();
            }
        });

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, dummyTextField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```